# How do i drill into any model from the store inside a controller or a route in ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have my promise function inside my route as

```
setupController: function (controller,model) {
    // Set the IndexController's `title`
    this.controllerFor('New').set('model', model);
    this.store.find('selectFill', { x: "20", y: "30" }).then(function (data) {
        controller.set('selectFill',data.?????);
    });
}
```

my model looks like this,

```
App.SelectFill = DS.Model.extend({
    users: DS.hasMany('user', {
        embedded: true
    })
});
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    userId:DS.attr('string'),
    department: DS.attr('string')
});
```

anyway once the promise get hit, i have the data in the store.My question is, how do i extract the users from it?

here is the class i get from the promise function.

Please refer to [this image here.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/102870683/ember-model.png)

*Users* array u can see on the bottom. but how do i get there from the promise callback?
sorry if my question is silly, but i'm still new to ember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.store.find('selectFill', { x: "20", y: "30" })` will resolve a array like object (`DS.AdapterPopulatedRecordArray`), in that sample is the `selectFills` variable. Because it's a kind of array, you can use forEach to iterate in each selectFill and get the user calling `selectFill.get('users')`. Like this:

```
setupController: function (controller,model) {
    // Set the IndexController's `title`
    this.controllerFor('New').set('model', model);
    this.store.find('selectFill', { x: "20", y: "30" }).then(function (selectFills) {
        selectFills.forEach(function(selectFill) {
            var users = selectFill.get('users');
            // do something with the users
        });
    });
}
```